how to make this UI using cardview

i want to create this kind of item using cardview but not able to get the transaparent curve
i have tried using transparent shapable image of curve shape but it did not work.
is this possible in android, i have seen this UI in the Dribbble but no current solution is present or article on this UI.
cardview is not necessary but it would look and reusable component as a recyclerview in case of cardview

@prats110892 could you help me in this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Add usual card view with FAB , prepare background image as shown using adobe photoshop, and set it as background and adjust corners
